# How to add conferenceDataVersion in Python?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I'm trying to create a Google Meet meeting using Google Calendar. After reading the documentation, I saw that there is a variable that is responsible for creating a meeting (`conferenceDataVersion`). I tried to declare it in different places, but it doesn't work. But simple events are created.

```
class GoogleCalendar:
    def add_event(self, calendar_id, body):
        return self.service.events().insert(
            calendarId = calendar_id, 
            body = body).execute()

obj = GoogleCalendar()
calendar = 'gmail@gmail.com'

event = {
  'conferenceDataVersion': 1,
  'summary': 'Тест',
  'location': 'Минск',
  'description': 'Описание',
  'start': {
    'date': '2023-05-25',
  },
  'end': {
    'date': '2023-05-26',
  },
  'conferenceData': {
      'createRequest': {
          'requestId': 'somestring',
          'conferenceSolutionKey': { 
              'type': 'hangoutsMeet' 
              },
      },
  }
}

event = obj.add_event(calendar_id = calendar, body = event)
```

I tried to declare conferenceDataVersion in add_event, but swore at the incorrect declaration of the variable.

```
version = 1
    def add_event(self, calendar_id, body, conference_data_version ):
        return self.service.events().insert(
            calendarId = calendar_id, 
            body = body, conferenceDataVersion = conference_data_version).execute()

event = obj.add_event(calendar_id = calendar, body = event, conference_data_version = version)
```

Comment: Is this thread an answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63689626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conferenceDataVersion` is the argument of `.insert` method:

```
service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=body, conferenceDataVersion=1)
```

I'd suggest using a [`google-calendar-simple-api`](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) (disclaimer: I might be biased because I'm the author of the library). Install it with:

```
pip install gcsa
```

Here is the equivalent code using `google-calendar-simple-api`:

```
from datetime import date
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from gcsa.event import Event
from gcsa.conference import ConferenceSolutionCreateRequest, SolutionType

calendar = 'gmail@gmail.com'
gc = GoogleCalendar(calendar)

event = Event(
    'Тест',
    location='Минск',
    description='Описание',
    start=date(2023, 5, 25),
    conference_solution=ConferenceSolutionCreateRequest(
        solution_type=SolutionType.HANGOUTS_MEET,
    )
)

event = gc.add_event(event)
```

Here is more info on [conference solutions](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conference.html).