# How to generate link for Google Meet call where meeting access type is open i.e. anyone can join?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, google-meet

I want to generate the Google Meet link, i.e., open for all.

#### PROBLEM:

How do we generate a link, i.e., open to all, so that everyone can join that meeting without the organizer manually admitting this or that person?

OR

Is there a way I can add attendees without sending mail to them? 
I tried finding some solution, but generating the open Google Meet link was not helpful.
My event looks something like this:

```
event =  {
    'summary': 'Open Google Meet',
    'description': 'An open Google Meet link.',
    "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": False,
    
    'start': {
    'dateTime': '2023-09-04T12:00:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
    },
    'start': {
    'dateTime': '2023-09-04T12:00:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
    },
    "visibility": "public",
    "anyoneCanAddSelf":True,
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                },
            "requestId": "Session"
            },
        },
}
```

Comment: Is this thread an answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63689626

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for commenting, no this is not a answer of my question in that queries the person is not able to add conference data in it where as i want to generate a meeting link which need to be open to all, what i mean currently the link is getting generated but the link is not open to all. Is it possible to make google meet link open to all? if not is there a way how i can add attendees without sending them mail

Comment: About the first part, what leads you to think that Google Meet / Google Calendar API supports this? About the second part, is that a programming question? If so, that should be posted in another post.